# Best place to put Microwave Oven

Tags: kitchens, bedroom, microwave-oven

What is the best place to keep Microwave Oven in home?

I thought to keep it my kitchen but my electrician said not to put it in kitchen along with LPG (but didn't provided any specific reason). What could be the possible reason of not keeping it in kitchen?

Is there any harm (due to Microwave or heat radiation) if I put it in my bedroom?

Comment: Your "electrician" is a buffoon! What does a microwave have to do with LPG??? There are plenty of other ignition sources to worry about, and the micro is not even one of them. And unless you live in a studio apartment keeping it in the bedroom is simply absurd.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microwaves go in the kitchen.  I would suggest that it is up in a higher spot so kids can't play with them.  That is a good reason they are often over ovens along with the venting.

Also from an electric point of view almost all microwaves require a 12A dedicated circuit.  For a kitchen you will probably have several runs like this and it is just bundled with those.  For a bedroom you would be basically running one circuit into a room for one outlet, where the rest of the room is on another.  Just a little odd.

From a safety stand-point microwaves draw a lot of current.  I guess there is more of a chance (albeit very low) that microwaves cause more fires due to current fluctuations than most other things.  I would much rather a fire in my kitchen than my bedroom or anyone's bedroom.

And practically speaking I remember living in the dorm and my roommate burning popcorn in the microwave... Good luck falling asleep with burnt popcorn smell.